# NSDatePicker formatter

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I use NSDatePicker in my app, but my date picker does not have zero in date/month/hour/etc as iCal's date picker. You can see the difference I talked about in highlighted part of two following images.

This is iCal's date picker:

[image: iCal date picker]

and this is my app's date picker:

[image: app date picker]

Would you please tell me how to have the formatter like iCal?

Comment: Finally, I found the answer, I need to change the locale of NSDatePicker

Comment: How do you obtain leading zeroes by changing the NSLocale ? I only understand how to change the locale to a different country or language.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried a lot of different locales, and ended up with Armenia for a good looking Norwegian format. I dont know why the Norwegian language code should trigger leading space in dates, for they are never used. Looks like a bug if not corrected. How to change the format used by the NSDatePicker - as setDateFormatter have no effect.

Comment: would you please care to fully answer your own question, now that you solved it? What locale do you use for the NSDatePicker, and how do you set it? Also, is there a way to tell date picker to use the Date-and-time system preference panel's format?

Comment: Same here... :/

Answer (score 2):

Apple uses a private method on `NSDatePicker` to force leading zeros to be shown regardless of locale.  You could do so as well, though it may not clear review in the Mac App Store.

Yes, you could force a locale that always shows a two-digit day field, but then some users would see the wrong field order or separator for their locale.

For Calendar.app / iCal, we can look at `CalendarUI.framework` in Hopper and see where they call a private method `_setForcesLeadingZeros:`.

[image: screenshot]

**You can call the private method with…**

```swift
let sel = Selector(("_setForcesLeadingZeroes:"))
let imp = class_getMethodImplementation(NSDatePicker.self, sel)
let impClosure = unsafeBitCast(
    imp,
    to: (@convention(c)(Any?, Selector?, Bool) -> Void).self)
impClosure(datePicker, sel, true)
```

Comment: `datePicker.setValue(true, forKey: "forcesLeadingZeroes")` also does the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Use NSDatePicker instance method `setDatePickerStyle:`

```
- (void)setDatePickerStyle:(NSDatePickerStyle)newStyle
```

Comment: There are three options in NSDatePickerStyle and I used NSTextFieldDatePickerStyle because I don't want a stepper or calendar/clock. But there are no luck for me.